# iGraph - k-core with graph.coreness underestimating some cores

Tags: r, igraph

I am using iGraph in R to calculate the k-cores for a set of 10 nodes. 8 of these nodes are connected, and have a degree of 5 or greater, and the other two nodes only have a degree of 3.

From my understanding of k cores, shouldn't the 8 nodes that are all connected, and that have a degree of at least 5 all be in a k-core with value 5? Two of these 8, are being given k-core value of 4 and 3 however.

See the reproducible graph below:

```
el = matrix(c("Ns-1","Ns-1","Ns-1","Ns-1","Ns-1","Ns-1","Ns-1","Ns-1","Ns-14","Ns-14","Ns-15","Ns-15","Ns-15","Ns-17","Ns-17","Ns-17","Ns-17","Ns-2","Ns-2","Ns-2","Ns-2","Ns-4","Ns-4","Ns-4","Ns-5","Ns-5","Ns-5","TAMU-7","Ns-14","Ns-15","Ns-17","Ns-2","Ns-4","Ns-5","TAMU-7","TAMU-8","Ns-15","Ns-17","Ns-17","Ns-4","Ns-18","Ns-2","Ns-4","Ns-5","Ns-18","Ns-4","Ns-5","TAMU-7","TAMU-8","Ns-5","TAMU-7","TAMU-8","TAMU-7","TAMU-8","Ns-18","TAMU-8"),nrow=28,ncol=2)

graph = graph.edgelist(el[,1:2],directed=F)

l <- layout.kamada.kawai(graph)
V(graph)$x <- l[,1]
V(graph)$y <- l[,2]

V(graph)$kCore = graph.coreness(graph)
V(graph)$degree = degree(graph)

layout(matrix(c(1,2), 1, 2))
plot(graph,
 main="Degree",
 vertex.size = 20,
 vertex.label = V(graph)$degree,
 vertex.label.color = "black",
 vertex.label.font = 1,
 vertex.label.family = "sans",
 vertex.label.cex = 1,
 vertex.color = "white")

plot(graph,
 main="K Cores",
 vertex.size = 20,
 vertex.label = V(graph)$kCore,
 vertex.label.color = "black",
 vertex.label.font = 1,
 vertex.label.family = "sans",
 vertex.label.cex = 1,
 vertex.color = "white")
```

... which produces this image (https://www.dropbox.com/s/unkkgodf8ppteyq/igraph.png?dl=0) of the same graph with degree shown on the left, and k-core shown on the right.

Basically, the top left and top right nodes should have both a degree and k-core of 3. The rest should be 5, however the two in the top middle are not.

Is this a bug in iGraph, or perhaps a mistake in my understanding of the k-core/`graph.coreness` algorithm?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> From my understanding of k cores, shouldn't the 8 nodes that are all connected, and that have a degree of at least 5 all be in a k-core with value 5? Two of these 8, are being given k-core value of 4 and 3 however.

No. The k-core is the part of the graph that you get if you remove all nodes with degree less than *k*, *iteratively*, meaning that if the degrees of some nodes fall below *k* due to the removal of *other* nodes, you have to remove these nodes as well. The remaining k-core is a subgraph where all nodes have degrees at least *k*. In your particular case, removing the node on the far left on your figure and removing the topmost node (in the upper right corner) decreases the degrees of two other nodes below 5 - so they will get removed as well.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I think I didn't get the iteratively part, and was only looking at the original degrees of nodes after removing nodes with degree less than k.